# how to solve this output in C++

Tags: c++, function

```
#‎include‬ <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;
typedef char Txt80[80];

int main()
{
 char *PText;

 Txt80 Txt = "Ur2GReAt";
 int N = 6;
 PText = Txt;

 while (N >=3)
 {
  Txt[N] = (isupper(Txt[N] ? tolower(Txt[N]):toupper(Txt[N])));
  cout << PText <<endl;
  N--;
  PText++;
 }
}

Output is :
 Ur2GRe
 r2GR
 2G
```

I am confused as according to the ternary operator used inside the loop, if the 6th value is a lowercase letter it should have converted it to uppercase. Here 'e' is in lowercase but still the output remains in lowercase and it simply is printing first 6 characters in the first run of the loop. Then in the 2nd run N is decremented and it is printing from 2. Please explain

Comment: What is `Txt80`? What output did you expect?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I expected if the 6th character is a uppercase letter it should  have been converted to lowecase else it should be in lowercase

Comment: `(isupper(Txt[N] ?` looks like it should be `isupper(Txt[N]) ?`

Comment: this should have converted lowecase e to upper case E. and the first output should have been Ur2GRE

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this line:

```
Txt[N] = (isupper(Txt[N] ? tolower(Txt[N]):toupper(Txt[N])));
```

sets `Txt[N]` to zero, effectively truncating the string there. The configuration of backets looks suspicious though - I wonder if you perhaps meant something like:

```
Txt[N] = (isupper(Txt[N]) ? tolower(Txt[N]) : toupper(Txt[N]));
```